# Should deterministic models be trained splitting into train, test datasets?

Tags: machine-learning, model, deterministic, stochastic

I'm studying the difference between GLM models (OLS, Logistic Regression, Zero Inflated, etc.), which are deterministic, since we can infer the parameters exactly, and some CART models (Random Forest, LightGBM, CatBoost, etc.) that are based on stochastic prediction.

What I've heard is that for stochastic models we should split into train and test to avoid over-fitting, fact that does not happen in deterministic models, because they use Linear Programming for finding the best parameters.

I've like to start some discussion about it.

My opinion is that it's true. Deterministic models are just equations solved, and it should not over-fit the data at all, and it differs from stochastic models based on randomness to make predictions.

But what I found was every course saying to split every datasets, independent if its deterministic or not.

Answer (score 1):

There is confusion over multiple concepts in your question.

- Should one use train/test set splits for deterministic models? If you are training a model for prediction, **absolutely!** The important thing to remember is that a prediction model needs to *generalize* to data other than the one used for training. This is evaluated using the test set. Even if a model is being learned simply as a means to explore the data, this is still recommended as a way to verify that one isn't just overfitting to the noise.
- The second point of confusion is that splitting into train and test sets avoid overfitting. This is not true per se. The separation is so that one can use the test set to verify if the model is overfitting. If the performance on the train and test sets differ "dramatically" then a model is likely overfitting and needs to be simplified, regularized, or otherwise constrained somehow.
- The other point pertains to what constitutes a stochastic model. All of the CART models that you mention are actually deterministic in the sense that, once you train then, they always yield exactly the same output for the same input. The stochasticity that you may have been referring is that the training uses random initializations which may result in quite different final models. If this is a concern (because of local optima for example), then use multiple initializations (a.k.a., multiple restarts, or Monte Carlo runs) to resolve them.
- Finally, you mentioned that deterministic models don't need this split because they cannot overfit. This is not true. Consider an SVM classifier with a Gaussian kernel of sufficiently small bandwidth. If solved to optimality, the training is deterministic and will most assuredly overfit the training data.